# HttpPostedFileBase is null - Posting files from AngularJS to MVC

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, file-upload, httppostedfilebase

Similar questions have been asked so many times, but there are no clear answers, I still have trouble getting mine to work.

This is the model in C#

```
public class SubmitModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
}
```

This is the MVC code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(SubmitModel model)
{
    // Here model.File and model.Files is always null
}
```

This is what I submitted using AngularJS

```
var data = {
    name: scope.name,     // This is passed to MVC successfully
    file: scope.files[0], // Doesn't even work with single file
    files: scope.files    // This is a FileList
};
$http.post("/umbraco/surface/MyController/Test", data).success(...);
```

If you want to know how I assign `scope.files`:

```
$('#upload').on('change', function (e) {
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.files = e.target.files;
    });
});
```

Could someone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

This is how it should be submitted

```
var data = new FormData();
angular.forEach(scope.item, function (value, key) {
    if (key == "files") {
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            data.append(value[i].name, value[i]); // Filename:File
        }
    } else {
        data.append(key, value);
    }
});

$http.post("/umbraco/surface/MyController/Test", data, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            }).success(...);
```

Then in MVC, we get the files from `Request.Files`, it won't be in the model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(SubmitModel model)
{
    var files = Request.Files;  // a collection of HttpPostedFileBase
    Save(model, files);
}
```

More info:
https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/878730/File-Upload-Using-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC